# How to use Python list?

Tags: python, list

I have python list like below.

```
lst = ['paragraph 1','paragraph 2','paragraph 3']
```

I'm trying to make corpus of them with Pattern library - http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-vector

As their example it should be like this ..

```
d1 = Document('paragraph 1')
d2 = Document('paragraph 2')
d3 = Document('paragraph 3')

corpus = Corpus(documents=[d1,d2,d3])
```

How can i make corpus liks this with my python list ?

Comment: You should change `list` to `paragraphs` or something else as you are losing access to the built-in `list`

Comment: Ah ;) I just showing example there. Not the actual list.

Comment: Even for an example it's bad practice but almost everybody does this on every question on this site...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lst = ['paragraph 1','paragraph 2','paragraph 3']
corpus = Corpus(documents=[Document(x) for x in lst])
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the map method

```
l = ['paragraph 1','paragraph 2','paragraph 3']
corpus = Corpus(map(Document, l))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not fully sure if this is what you want but I'm assuming you need a `list comprehension`.

```
paragraphs = ['paragraph 1','paragraph 2','paragraph 3']
corpus = Corpus(documents=[Document(d) for d in paragraphs])
```

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't specify whether it should use list comprehension or not. In the particular example given in the question, list comprehension is a fine and concise solution. However, in case the op is not asking for list comprehension for about a more general solution to working with lists in Python, here is the more verbose iterative method:

```
paragraphs = ['paragraph 1','paragraph 2','paragraph 3']
docs = []
for p in paragraphs:
    docs.append(Document(p))
corpus = Corpus(documents=docs)
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why the OP would ever need to do this.

Comment: In this example, he shouldn't, as noted in the answer. I am merely putting this out there in case iteration really was what he was looking for, while giving an example in which list comprehension was a better choice.